# Magento - Add products to cart from supplier site

Tags: php, magento

I have the following scenario:
Customer goes to myMagentoshop and clicks a link to browse products at a supplier website.
Customer adds products to cart at the supplier website and when finished clicks a "send to merchant cart" button which calls myMagentoshop with an XML feed of the products.
myMagentoshop parses the XML feed and ads the products to the cart and then displays the cart.

What I'm asking for is pointers in the right way to go about this and the correct terminology. Should I build a custom webservice/adapter/? for myMagentoshop?

I have recently made a php script that reads an xml file and imports products via the API but this is not quite the same...

Comment: I am interested in the idea of what you are trying to do.  I've flagged this question for migration to the Magento stack exchange

Comment: There are various ways todo so including the one you did. Let me ask you what do you think importing order via xml is not good? And what u mean by "it's not quit same"

Comment: Perhaps it is the same. Would you suggest making a php script that takes the XML as argument? I can use the API to add to add the products to the cart. If I send the user to the cart page will the products then be displayed?